# Vertical line between two anchor elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgSKO.png)

I need to create a vertical line between two empty elements in HTML. Elements and text between the anchors should be rendered. The vertical line should appear to the left of the text and not influence the style of it and not even interrupt it.

My HTML-Code looks basically like the snippet below. There are some spans that serve as anchor-elements such as e.g. `<span id="start_line-1"/>` and `<span id="end_line-1"/>` that mark where the vertical line has to start and where to end. The lines can span over several paragraphs and do not correlate with the element's hierarchy. Any idea how to do this in jquery or javascript?

```
  <div>
        <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,<br /> sed diam nonumy eirmod
                tempor invidunt ut labore<span id="start_line-1"/> et dolore magna aliquyam
                erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
                Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est<br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
                eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
                At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
                no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>
        <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,<br /> sed diam nonumy eirmod
                tempor invidunt ut labore<span id="end_line-1"/> et dolore magna aliquyam
                erat, sed diam voluptua. 
        </p>
        <span id="start_line-2"/>
        <span>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet<br /> clita kasd
                gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est<br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
        <span id="end_line-2"/>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please add an image to your post. Please create a screenshot and draw this lines on it.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the | character?

Comment: Just added a screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

Without using `<div>` inside `<p>` tags it is possible to achieve what you want.

```css
.vertical-line {
    border-left: 4px solid red;
    height: auto;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.transparent {
 border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-line transparent">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
</div>
<div class="vertical-line">
  sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
  erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est<br /> 
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
  eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
  no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,<br /> 
  sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed 
</div>
<div class="vertical-line transparent">
  diam voluptua.
</div>
<div class="vertical-line">
  At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet<br /> 
  clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est<br /> 
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, this would work if the vertical line wouldn't overlap with the text structure. If you look at <span id="start_line-1"/> and <span id="end_line-1"/> there is a closing and an opening paragraph in between.

Comment: This is just because `<p>` can't contain `<div>`.

Comment: Updated without `<p>` elements.

Comment: Thanks for the update but the solution doesn't work, because the vertical lines will be an addition to an HTML that already contains complex nested HTML elements with associated CSS styles that I cannot manipulate how you did in your example without "destroying" other elements/styles. The HTML is transformed from XML (where the line start/end are also anchors) via xQuery/XSLT- I can manipulate the HTML-outcome there, but I tried for a while to find a HTML/CSS-based solution and couldn't find anything, due to overlapping hierarchies. I thought there might be some javascript or jquery solution.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I understood from your question, following is what you need. If you want a specific section of a paragraph alone to have a vertical line, enclose it within a span like below. Go ahead and run the code,

```css
span.container:before {
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 5px;
  left:0;
  height: 100%;
}

span.container {
  position: relative;
  padding-left:10px;
  display:block;
}

div.main {
  padding-left:10px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="main">
   <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,<br /> sed diam nonumy eirmod
      tempor invidunt ut labore
   <span class="container">
      et dolore magna aliquyam
      erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
      Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est<br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit
      amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
      eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
      At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
      no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </p>
      <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,<br /> sed diam nonumy eirmod
         tempor invidunt ut labore
   </span>
   et dolore magna aliquyam
   erat, sed diam voluptua. 
   </p>
   <span class="container">
      <span>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet<br /> clita kasd
      gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est<br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
   </span>
</div>
```

Instead of marking the start/end with spans (I do not know if it is possible to accomplish the vertical line with those spans), you can enclose the content inside a container

Comment: As far as I can see the HTMl-Code is not valid. I should produce valid code though..

Answer (score 0):

```css
.obj .obj1 {
  position: relative;
  border-left: 4px solid red;
  padding-left: 5px;
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class='obj'>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,<br /> sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore<span id="start_line-1" /> et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
    clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est<br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
    eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,<br /> sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore<span id="end_line-1" /> et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>


  <span class='obj1'>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet<br /> clita kasd
                gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est<br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>

</div>
```

You can use css as mentioned above.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately the line should span over several paragraphs and also be able to start/end within one. That is why I can't use a container with a border. I just put a screenshot in my original post to make the issue clearer.

Comment: I have updated the post according to the clearer view seen.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try using HTML entity like — and rotate it using css.
transform: rotate(90deg)

Comment: the entity is "&mdash;"